# Codeigniter profile page function keeps looping

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am working on a website in which i want to create user profiles. I got a page where i list all the users in a table. I made a button to link to the profile page of a user. The profile page gets the right data from the database, but the page keeps loading all the views over and over again beneath each other.

This is the code for filling the users table:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Naam</th>
            <th>Voornaam</th>
            <th>Gebruikersnaam</th>
            <th>Geboortedatum</th>
            <th>Studienummer</th>
            <th>Aanmaakdatum</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($records as $record){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $record->usr_naam; ?></td>
            <td><?= $record->usr_voorNaam; ?></td>
            <td><?= $record->usr_userNaam; ?></td>
            <td><?= $record->usr_geboorteDatum; ?></td>
            <td><?= $record->usr_studyNr; ?></td>
            <td><?= $record->usr_timeStamp; ?></td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-outline" href="<?php echo site_url('patient/id/'.$record->usr_id);?>"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-outline" type="button"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-outline" type="button"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

every row generates a button with a link to the user's profile page. 
for example: `http://localhost/nemo-v2/patient/id/1`

this link refers to id function in the patient controller.
this is the code of the id function

```
public function id(){
    $userid = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->load->model('User_model');
    $data['record'] = $this->User_model->getUser($userid);

    $this->load->view('templates/head');
    $this->load->view('templates/menu');
    $this->load->view('pages/patient', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

After the user data is selected from the database the views are called to show the profile page. the problem here is that the program keeps looping through the id function and keeps stacking the views beneath each other.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkOho.jpg

this is the code of the patient view. For now I just use var_dump() to show the result from the database. All the rest is just HTML with some dummy data. Eventualy this needs to be replaced with data from the database.

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                    <div class="ibox-title">
                        <h5>Profile detail</h5>
                        <div class="ibox-tools">
                            <a class="collapse-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a class="edit-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ibox-content">
                        <h4><strong>Jef</strong></h4>
                        <p><i class="col-lg-1 fa fa-map-marker"></i> Genk 3600</p>
                        <p><i class="col-lg-1 fa fa-birthday-cake"></i> 06/02/1985</p>
                        <p><i class="col-lg-1 fa fa-envelope"></i> jef.jef@uhasselt.be</p>
                        <p><i class="col-lg-1 fa fa-phone"></i> 0473 23876546</p>
                        <h5>
                            About me
                        </h5>
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitat.
                        </p>
                        <div class="user-button">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-block" href="<?php echo site_url('statistics');?>"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i> &nbsp;Statistics</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-block" href="<?php echo site_url('alerts');?>"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i> &nbsp;Alerts</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                    <div class="ibox-title">
                        <h5>Devices</h5>
                        <div class="ibox-tools">
                            <a class="collapse-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a class="edit-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ibox-content">
                        <h5><i class="col-lg-1 fa fa-heartbeat"></i> Pulse</h5>
                        <h5><i class="col-lg-1 fa fa-heart"></i> Smart scale</h5>
                        <h5><i class="col-lg-1 fa fa-arrows-v"></i> <h5>Blood pressure monitor</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                    <div class="ibox-title">
                        <h5>Alerts</h5>
                        <div class="ibox-tools">
                            <a class="collapse-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a class="edit-link">
                                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ibox-content">
                        <h5><i class="col-lg-1 fa fa-medkit"></i> High risk: 1</h5>
                        <h5><i class="col-lg-1 fa fa-warning"></i> Medium risk: 4</h5>
                        <h5><i class="col-lg-1 fa fa-check"></i> Normal: 12</h5>
                        <h5><i class="col-lg-1 fa fa-eye-slash"></i> Missed: 0</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                <div class="ibox-title">
                    <h5>Extra information</h5>
                    <div class="ibox-tools">
                        <a class="collapse-link">
                            <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ibox-content">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eu dui sed nulla iaculis rutrum a id tortor. Vestibulum feugiat bibendum ipsum, in egestas velit volutpat in. Mauris lacus quam, accumsan eu nulla ac, tincidunt tristique urna. Etiam molestie facilisis elit, ut molestie orci commodo semper. Suspendisse id leo nec ipsum lobortis maximus pretium in ipsum. Praesent vehicula, est eleifend tristique vestibulum, mauris ipsum molestie massa, eget lobortis quam lectus vitae odio. Suspendisse quis lacus at justo malesuada tincidunt. Quisque ut facilisis erat, eget aliquam ipsum. Maecenas fermentum augue mauris, sed commodo purus sodales nec. Nullam bibendum quam in elit faucibus, et tincidunt ex ultricies. Nam eu elementum ex, ac vehicula arcu.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eu dui sed nulla iaculis rutrum a id tortor. Vestibulum feugiat bibendum ipsum, in egestas velit volutpat in. Mauris lacus quam, accumsan eu nulla ac, tincidunt tristique urna. Etiam molestie facilisis elit, ut molestie orci commodo semper. Suspendisse id leo nec ipsum lobortis maximus pretium in ipsum. Praesent vehicula, est eleifend tristique vestibulum, mauris ipsum molestie massa, eget lobortis quam lectus vitae odio. Suspendisse quis lacus at justo malesuada tincidunt. Quisque ut facilisis erat, eget aliquam ipsum. Maecenas fermentum augue mauris, sed commodo purus sodales nec. Nullam bibendum quam in elit faucibus, et tincidunt ex ultricies. Nam eu elementum ex, ac vehicula arcu.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eu dui sed nulla iaculis rutrum a id tortor. Vestibulum feugiat bibendum ipsum, in egestas velit volutpat in. Mauris lacus quam, accumsan eu nulla ac, tincidunt tristique urna. Etiam molestie facilisis elit, ut molestie orci commodo semper. Suspendisse id leo nec ipsum lobortis maximus pretium in ipsum. Praesent vehicula, est eleifend tristique vestibulum, mauris ipsum molestie massa, eget lobortis quam lectus vitae odio. Suspendisse quis lacus at justo malesuada tincidunt. Quisque ut facilisis erat, eget aliquam ipsum. Maecenas fermentum augue mauris, sed commodo purus sodales nec. Nullam bibendum quam in elit faucibus, et tincidunt ex ultricies. Nam eu elementum ex, ac vehicula arcu.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eu dui sed nulla iaculis rutrum a id tortor. Vestibulum feugiat bibendum ipsum, in egestas velit volutpat in. Mauris lacus quam, accumsan eu nulla ac, tincidunt tristique urna. Etiam molestie facilisis elit, ut molestie orci commodo semper. Suspendisse id leo nec ipsum lobortis maximus pretium in ipsum. Praesent vehicula, est eleifend tristique vestibulum, mauris ipsum molestie massa, eget lobortis quam lectus vitae odio. Suspendisse quis lacus at justo malesuada tincidunt. Quisque ut facilisis erat, eget aliquam ipsum. Maecenas fermentum augue mauris, sed commodo purus sodales nec. Nullam bibendum quam in elit faucibus, et tincidunt ex ultricies. Nam eu elementum ex, ac vehicula arcu.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php var_dump($record); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is no error in the model because the right data is selected from the database. I have searched for a few days now, but i can't figure out what the problem is.
I am using CodeIgniter 3.0 (release candidate 3). I have tested my code in CodeIgniter 2.2.1 but with the same result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in your `id()` method of the patient controller, can you comment out all the view loading functions and just `var_dump($data)` ? What are your results?

Comment: Yes, I just get my array from the database one time. So the function id() is not looping.

Comment: ok now only add one view at a time. Maybe start with this `$this->load->view('pages/patient', $data);` by itself, and see what happens

Comment: It goes wrong when i add the footer view. I will check for any errors in this view. Thanks for the help I'll keep you updated.

Comment: ok, no problem, anytime

Comment: Thank you, the problem was a script in the footer view. The script is used by Inspinia (bootstrap theme). I will let the guys from inspinia know which script was causing the problem.

Comment: awesome. Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by a script in the footer.

```
<script src="/inspinia_admin-v1.9.2/js/inspinia.js"></script>
```

The script is from Inspinia (bootstrap theme). I will let the guys from Inspinia know that there is something going wrong with this script.

I don't mean by this that Inspinia is not a good theme on the contrary Inspinia is an awesome theme with a lot of functionality.

UPDATE: I did some debugging in the script and came to the conclusion that this function was causing the problem.

```
// Append config box / Only for demo purpose
$.get("skin-config.html", function (data) {
    $('body').append(data);
});
```

Apparently this is a function used only for demo purposes, so I just commented it out and everything works fine.